# insert a new line after inserting a horizontal line

Tags: vba, ms-word

i'm completely new to visual basic.
this is my first code.

I want to run a macro that inserts a horizontal line, (bottom border) and then adds a new line below that horizontal line.
i got this code to insert the horizontal line, but i dont know how to add the new line below that

thank you

```
`Sub BottomBorder()
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
    .Color = wdColorAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This inserts a paragraph border which looks like a line but is not. You want another below it?

Comment: Please don't use "basic" flag when referring to "vba". These are two separate coding languages.